# What is the purpose of dbClearResult() in DBI/RMySQL/RMariaDB?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql, r-dbi

SQL novice here. In the [Hello World section of the RMySQL github page](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL#hello-world), there is the following -

```
# You can fetch all results:
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl = 4")
dbFetch(res)
dbClearResult(res)
```

I don't understand the purpose of `dbClearResult()`. This is important to me because I'm working with a few large tables and `dbClearResult(rs)` can be very slow at times (taking minutes to complete). However, if I go into the mysql shell I can simply kill a query instantaneously.

So, what is the purpose of `dbClearResult()` and is there any way to avoid it or speed it up?

Answer (score 2):

From the [DBI documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbClearResult) for `dbClearResult`:

> Frees all resources (local and remote) associated with a result set.
>   In some cases (e.g., very large result sets) this can be a critical
>   step to avoid exhausting resources (memory, file descriptors, etc.)

Comment: I'm not voting down, but *only* pointing to documentation (without profounding further) is a very lousy answer, even more when the original question provides a better solution to its problem, albeit outside R.